# HTML5 WebWorker and Rails 3 Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement an HTML5 WebWorker and I am using rails 3. I have this in my js code:

//When body(DOM) is ready

```
$(function() { 
....
..
    //test html5 webworkers
    $('#test_html5_workers').click(function() {
      var worker=new Worker('play.js');
      worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
      }, false);

      worker.postMessage('Hello World'); // Send data to our worker.
    });
..
....
)};
```

and in another file I have this (in play.js)

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  self.postMessage(e.data);
}, false);
```

I am currently getting this error:

> Script file not found: play.js

I have tried other file path names with no luck.

Any ideas why I am getting this since both files are in the same directory, assets/javascripts?
I am using Firefox 17.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The javascript file (play.js) should go in the public folder, or at least that's what I did to get it working.

Answer (score -1):

This works on mine.

```
(function() { 
    //test html5 webworkers
    $('#test').on('click', function(){
        if(window.Worker){
            var worker = new Worker('test.js');
            worker.onmessage = function(e){
                alert('worker said: ' + e.data);
            }
            worker.postMessage('start');
        }
    });
})();

//test.js
self.onmessage = function(e){
    if(e.data === 'start'){
        self.postMessage('booyeah');
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a new file, put the first code in, put the second one in another file called 'test.js', nothing